# How to get the size of the first x minutes of a video using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to input a time range, and get the size in bytes of a video.

For example, if I would like to extract the first two minutes of a video, I would do:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss 0 -t 120 out.mp4
```

But I don't really want to extract it, I just want to fetch the size of it if I would have.

Answer (score 0):

You would run, on Windows,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -ss 0 -t 120 -c copy -y -f mov NUL 2>&1 | grep -oP "(?<=Lsize=)\s*[0-9]+\w+" | sed s/\s//g
```

This remuxes two minutes of the source file and extracts the muxed size of the media.

For linux, replace NUL with `/dev/null`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ran this command on an mp4 file, and got this response: `31939kB` so I downloaded exactly `32705536` bytes of the file. The video goes up to 01:49 (109 seconds) and not 120 seconds. Any idea why?

Comment: The size does not include the size of the metadata in the original file nor the size of additional streams beside the highest-rated video and audio stream.

Comment: The file has only one video stream and one audio stream. And the metadata shouldn't be more than a few bytes, right?

Comment: Metadata in MOV can be anywhere from 0.5 to 3% of the entire file.

Comment: Interesting. So is it possible to calculate the size of the metadata as well? I want to get the file size of the exact time (two different commands will be fine as well)

Comment: btw, i'm using mp4 files, i've updated the question accordingly